# Gathering Length of all DXF objects in python

Tags: python, ezdxf

I am trying to write a script to pull the total length of all features in a dxf file using ezdxf and output the result

This is what I've written so far and I'm not getting accurate results when I do the math by hand. Any help would be appreciated!

```
import ezdxf
import math

# Load the DXF file
doc = ezdxf.readfile("Bumper Spacer.dxf")
msp = doc.modelspace()
lines = msp.query("LINE")
plines = msp.query("POLYLINE")
circles = msp.query("CIRCLE")
splines = msp.query("SPLINE")

perimeter = 0
# Iterate through entities and print their types
for entity in plines:
    points = list(entity.points())
    length = 0
    for i in range(len(points)):
        x1, y1, bulge = points[i]
        if i == len(points) - 1:
            x2, y2, _ = points[0]  # Connect the last point back to the first for a closed POLYLINE
        else:
            x2, y2, _ = points[i + 1]
        length = length + math.sqrt((x2 - x1) ** 2 + (y2 - y1) ** 2)
        print(f"SEGMENT: {entity} X1: {x1} Y1: {y1} X2: {x2} Y2: {y2}")
    print(f"PLINE: {length}")
    perimeter = perimeter + length
for entity in circles:
    radius = entity.dxf.radius
    length = 2 * math.pi * radius
    print(f"CIRCLE: {length}")
    perimeter = perimeter + length
for entity in lines:
    length = math.sqrt((entity.dxf.start[0] - entity.dxf.end[0]) ** 2 + (entity.dxf.start[1] - entity.dxf.end[1]) ** 2)
    print(f"LINE: {length}")
    perimeter = perimeter + length
for entity in splines:
    puntos = entity.get_control_points()
    length = 0
    for i in range(len(puntos) - 1):
        length = length + math.sqrt((puntos[i][0] - puntos[i + 1][0]) ** 2 + (puntos[i][1] - puntos[i + 1][1]) **2 )
    print(f"SPLINE: {length}")
    perimeter = perimeter + length
print(perimeter)
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Have you analyzed where your code is getting different than expected results?  The code for Polyline length does not account for arc segments,  and for spline you are measuring the lengths between control points, which may not be the actual spline length.